# How to get size of TableView column?

Tags: java, javafx, width, tableview, tablecolumn

Is there any way to get the current size of a TableView column? I've haven't even been able to find the question online which makes me think I've missed something since I can't be the first one to need this functionality.

If that isn't possible, is there any way to set the size of a TableView column? That would also solve my issue although I'd prefer getting the size. `setFixedCellSize(double)` looked promising, but I couldn't get it to work.

I want to have a TextField above each column in my TableView with the same size as the column it's above. If there's a better way to accomplish that, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Property-Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/index.html). But the width-Property of a TableColumn or TextField is read-only. This is correct, since the width and height is part of the layout process in rendering the whole window.

So you need to set the three sizes, min - pref - max width, for the TextField with the currently width from the TableColumn. It seems to me the prefered way to take the TableColumns width as the master for the TextFields width.

Now, even on manually resizing, your TextField stays the same width as the "bound" TableColumns width.

A little [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TableTest extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField field = new TextField();

    TableView<String> table = new TableView<>();
    TableColumn<String, String> column = new TableColumn("Header Text");
    table.getColumns().add(column);

    field.prefWidthProperty().bind(column.widthProperty());
    field.minWidthProperty().bind(column.widthProperty());
    field.maxWidthProperty().bind(column.widthProperty());

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll(field, table);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```